# What is this syntax? int i{10}

Tags: c++, syntax

I found a weird syntax when i read A Tour Of C++. What is this syntax meaning? int i{10}

```
void g()
{
int i{10};
cout << i;
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the book also explains what that syntax means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax is used to **initialize variables.**

There are three ways to initialize variables in C++.

The first one, known as **copy-initialization**

*type var_name = initial_value;*

```
int x = 0;
```

A second method, known as **constructor initialization**

*type var_name (initial_value);*

```
int x (0);
```

Third method, known as **uniform initialization**,  **(C++11)**:

*type var_name {initial_value};*

```
int x {0};
```

Comment: You made up those bolded terms. The first one is called *copy-initialization*. The second and third are called *direct-initialization*. The third one also uses *list-initialization*.

Comment: @M.M When you need to distinguish between the two, the second is *direct-non-list-initialization* (a term invented by the library fundamentals TS); the third is *direct-list-initialization*; and then `int x = {0};` is *copy-list-initialization*. Apparently the committee hasn't needed to invent *copy-non-list-initialization* yet.